# Xbox one profiles

Tags: xbox-network, xbox-one

I live in Brazil, and I had to create an US account, since here our catalog was too restricted. I also have a Brazilian account, to buy special offers, but my main account is the US account. I now have an Xbox One, and the marketplace is pretty much the same.

Can I change the region to my country, and buy using my currency, without changing the location of my US profile?

Answer (score 1):

**No**

Xbox Profiles are bound to a marketplace region and their offers, including their currency. You can migrate profiles from from one region to another.

If you switch your current US profile to the Brazilian marketplace you will forfeit the remaining currency on the account till you migrate back (I think) and not be able to buy any US content, your former US account will become a Brazilian account.